# Setting text in the background of a view

Tags: android, android-layout

In linear layout I have multiple text views. I want to add a translucent text in the background of the text view ie I have a block of text and I want the background to be the number 3.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK,it is not possible.instead,you should use a background image for your textview for meeting your need.